# Python - Less than or Equal To Compare with two lists?

Tags: python, list, compare

New to Python, so this is probably a stupid question, but I have not been able to figure this one out after a day of research and executing code.

I'd like to take two lists of integers (results and settings) and compare them in the format:

```
(Setting# - 0.1) <= Result# <= (Setting# +0.1)
```

I need to do this for all #'s in the lists.

For example, if `Result1=4.6` and `Setting1=4.3`, I want it to compare 4.2 <= 4.6 <= 4.4 (which would result in a failure, as it is too far outside my tolerance of `0.1`.  Once it compares that, I would want it to continue through the list until finished, of course.

This does not appear to work as I have it.  Any ideas?

```
results = [Result1, Result2, Result3, Result4, Result5, Result6]
settings = [Setting1, Setting2, Setting3, Setting4, Setting5, Setting6]
for n in results and m in settings:
    if (m-.1) <= n <= (m+.1): #compare values with a + or - 0.1 second error tolerance
    print 'ok'
else:
    print 'fail'
print 'Done'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `zip` to iterate over `results` and `settings` in tandem:

```
for n, m in zip(results, settings):
    if m - 0.1 <= n <= m + 0.1:
        print 'ok'
    else:
        print 'fail'
print 'Done'
```

Comment: You beat both of us to it? Inconceivable!

Comment: @Darksabre: If you want to understand why this works, you may want to try `print`ing `zip(results, settings)`.

Comment: I will try this first thing tomorrow morning.  Thanks for the quick answers!  Looking forward to it :)

Comment: Works just like it should :)  Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to combine the two lists:

```
for n, m in zip(results, settings):
    if (m-.1) <= n <= (m+.1):
        print 'ok'
    else:
        print 'fail'
```

`zip()` creates a new list made by combining each nth element from each input sequence:

```
>>> a = range(5)
>>> b = 'abcde'
>>> zip(a, b)
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'd'), (4, 'e')]
```

You can use [`all()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) to short-circuit testing; `all()` returns `False` as soon as possible. We use [`itertools.izip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) here instead to avoid creating a whole new list where perhaps only the first few pairs might be tested:

```
from itertools import izip

if all((m-.1) <= n <= (m+.1) for n, m in izip(results, settings)):
    print 'All are ok'
else:
    print 'At least one failed'
```

Comment: I'm not sure how much benefit you'll get out of `all` and the genexp here unless you also use `izip`… but I'd still probably write it that way anyway.

Comment: @abarnert: for shorter lists, the difference between `izip()` and `zip()` may well lie with `zip()`; a tradeoff between memory and speed is to be made here somewhere. Of course, on Python 3, the choice is moot.

Comment: (Unless Python3, where `zip` does return an iterator instead of a list.)

Comment: @chapner: Yes, but in 3.x the `print` statements will be an error, so the OP's question (and Martijn's answer) are obviously 2.x.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: You're forgetting that if you don't consume the entire iterator, `izip` doesn't have to finish generating it. In effect, it short-circuits when `all` does. So, if your list is long enough for the short-circuiting of `all` to make a difference, it's probably long enough for leaving the zip unfinished to make a difference too.

Comment: This works great as well.  There are cases where izip will work perfect in my application.  Thanks all :)

Answer (score 1):

And as almost always with lists and python, it's possible to do in a single line:

```
print('ok' if all(setting - 0.1 <= result <= setting + 0.1 
    for setting, result in zip(settings, results)) else 'fail')
```

Comment: I like this single line idea.  There is so much to learn in python, its insane!  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Setting = [4,3,5,6]
Result = [3,3.02,5.001,8]

print([ (x - 0.1) <= y <= (x + 0.1) for x,y in zip(Setting, Result)])
```

and you get the result as a list of booleans

```
>>> 
[False, True, True, False]
```